# External stylesheet from github not linking

Tags: html, css

So till now I always used stylesheets which are in the same folder as my website, but I want to be more flexible and work on my layout via github. So i uploaded the css file and used the raw link. I noticed that I can't use it. Is it even possible to use stylesheets from websites? I tried to find an answer on the internet but I couldn't find an article about this issue.
Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Goetterescu/Website/main/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello there</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/Goetterescu/Website/main/styles.css">
</head>
```

I used https://gitcdn.link/ to serve the stylesheet since Github was serving it with the wrong stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

You should use this type of file path to your css file. GitHub file directories should point to the relative path of the linked file within the repository.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello there</h1>
</body>
</html>
```